# How to Deploy Data in an SSDT Unit Test but Only for the Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, deployment, sql-server-data-tools

I have successfully begun to write SSDT unit tests for my recent stored procedure changes. One thing I've noticed is that I wind up creating similar test data for many of the tests. This suggests to me that I should create a set of test data during deployment, as a post-deploy step. This data would then be available to all subsequent tests, and there would be less need for lengthy creation of pre-test scripts. Data which is unique to a given unit test would remain in pre-test scripts.

The problem is that the post-deploy script would run not only during deployment for unit tests, but also during deployment to a real environment. Is there a way to make the post-deploy step (or parts of it) run only during the deployment for an SSDT unit test?

I have seen that the test settings in the app.config include the database project configuration to deploy. But I don't see how to cause different configurations to use different SQLCMD variables.

I also see that we can set different SQLCMD variables in the publish profiles, but I don't see how the unit test settings in app.config can reference different publish profiles.

Comment: Look at the contents of the .sqlproj file - see how there is a "Debug" and "Release" property group with different settings. You can add a "Test" configuration and have a different default value for the SQLCMD variable in that case versus Debug/Release. Then set the configuration to "Test" in the unit test configuration dialog.

Comment: @KevinCunnane: I would have tried that, but I have had bad experiences in the past with making project changes which are not supported by the Visual Studio UI. Such changes have been lost in the past, because the change is not reflected in Visual Studio's object model for the project. It's a maintainability issue - in order to understand that variable, it's necessary to read the .sqlproj file. But there's no indication in the UI that there's any reason to go read the .sqlproj file!

Comment: I understand - that's why I made this a comment rather than a full answer. It's a workaround for your issue but not an ideal solution...

Answer (score 1):

You could use an IF-statement, checking @@SERVERNAME and only running your Unit Testing code on the Unit Test server(s), with the same type of test for the other environments.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could make use of the Build number in your TFS Build Definition. If the Build contains, for example the substring 'test', you could execute the the test-code, otherwise not. Then you make sure to set an appropriate build number in all your builds.

Comment: How would I access the build number from within the test?

Comment: I use SQLCMD Variables, for example $(ChangeSets) & $(VersionNumber), in my SQL. I was thinking you could do the same, perhaps you need a file or table for intermediate storage.